# Is an adverb fit for this sentence/phrase?

Tags: meaning-in-context, parsing

In the NY Times headline:

"The Fight to Save New York’s Extravagantly ’80s Subway Entrance"

is the adverb Extravagantly a correct use there? shouldn't it be Extravagant instead?

Answer (score 2):

The adverb *extravagantly* is used correctly here.  *80's* is being used as an adjective, meaning "of the 1980s".  So the subway entrance is not just of the 1980s, it's *extravagantly* of the 1980s.

Comment: At least, that's the only and right interpretation. Whether the author intended it this way is another matter :)